# Makefile pattern rules and wildcard - how to pass two parameters from target to recipe

Tags: gnu-make

I'm trying to pass parameters through file names in phony to a stata do-file, and I'm wondering if there is a way to get around the restriction of only one pattern rule for my situation.

In phony:

```
test: file1_2005_2010.dta file1_2004_2008.dta
```

In another makefile I now want to parse these start and end years, and in theory this would work by parsing 2005_2010 and 2004_2008 in the stata do file:

```
file1_%.dta: 
     cd path/folder && YEAR=$* $(STATA) dofile.do
```

But the problem is that some of the prerequisites have only the start year in it, which have to be made dynamically so I can use % only for 2005 in this case:

```
   file1_2005_2010.dta: file2_2005.dta
         cd path/folder && $(STATA) dofile.do

   file1_%_2010.dta: file2_%.dta
         cd path/folder && YEAR=$* $(STATA) dofile.do
```

I don't necessarily need 2010 to match any prerequisite filenames, it just needs to be passed to the recipe. Using a wildcard for 2010 (`file1_%_*.dta`) doesnt' work either if the target doesn't already exist.

Is there any way around these two restrictions?

Comment: I don't get it. Could you show a few versions of the recipe without automatic variables? Boiler plate a few, see what we're up against.

Comment: @Andreas I added the recipe. We're kinda hacking the makefiles to work with stata, so I didn't want to confuse anyone. But it's basically just executing a stata do file, and we can pass the YEAR parameter to this program to create the correct target dta file.

Answer (score 1):

This will first extract the end year part from the target and then prefix it with the start year in the pattern. Walking through it step by step.

To get the target filename we use automatic variable `$@`:

```
YEAR=$@
# Year is file1_2005_2010.dta
```

Remove the suffix `.dta`:

```
YEAR=$(basename $@)
# Year is file1_2005_2010
```

Exchange _ with whitespace to create words:

```
YEAR=$(subst _, ,$(basename $@))
# Year is "file1 2005 2010"
```

Extract last word:

```
YEAR=$(lastword $(subst _, ,$(basename $@)))
# Year is 2010
```

Finally prefix with start year:

```
YEAR=$*_$(lastword $(subst _, ,$(basename $@)))
# Year is 2005_2010
```

Comment: Nice, I had tried some variation of this to extract the last year, but didn't know about adding basename. So how would I refer to the target file in order to keep the flexibility (e.g. either 2005_2010 or 2004_2008 or any other combination of years)? File1_%_*.dta doesn't work if the file doesn't already exist. Thanks!

Comment: When I tried creating YEAR, I got an error `*** insufficient number of arguments (1) to function 'word'` Any idea why this would be?

Comment: @HHJ Hm, lastword is internally interpreted as `$(word $(words text), text)`. Maybe it's a macro with leaky abstraction with regards to error handling... meaning `$(words text)` turn out empty?

Comment: Nm, I had the wrong year in the filename in phony... sorry about that. The YEAR parameter works now. What are your thoughts about the target file? I still have file1_%_2010.dta as the target right now but this would need to be dynamic, but the * wildcard wouldn't work here instead of 2010.

Comment: @HHJ Good to hear! :-) Whenever I want dynamic rules in the sense they are defined from what exists on file system (or not), I start by saving the result of find in a shell: `$(shell find src -name *.dta)`. Then process the strings and hack it together somehow. I suppose you could take a look at `eval` since it supposedly can generate rules and recipes from list permutations etc, but it's advanced to the point it's more fun than productive. And quite often it's not even much fun.

Comment: But if the file doesn't exist `find` won't work right? I'll look into eval...

Comment: Also I tried this but I got the same `insufficient number of arguments` error again, but do you know of something that could make the following work in which the 2005_2010 is contained in %, and then the dependency would parse it? `file1_%.dta: file2_$(word 2, $(subst _, ,$(basename $@))).dta`

Comment: `shell` can take an arbitrary complex shell command. If it turns out empty, return something based on that. Sorry, got nothing in mind to fix the big picture. Automatic variable `$@` is only available in recipes so it expands to nothing.